# Android sharing file not working

Tags: android, android-intent, file-sharing, android-fileprovider

Please help, I'm newbie in android programming and sorry for my english.
I'm working on android sharing file "PDF" into other apps, the process was followed from [Android Sharing File](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html) but still not working, always displays an error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /temp.PDF

errors above happen when click the file.

DownloadListPDF.java

```
try {
    fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(DownloadListPDF.this,
            "id.dutapulsa.bayartagihan.extension.FileProvider",
            requestFile); //<-- in this line that shows errors
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="DownloadListPDF"
    android:label="List Struk"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="id.dutapulsa.bayartagihan.extension.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

filepaths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path path="pdf/" name="pdf" />
</paths>
```

and from logcat

```
06-25 09:47:18.282: W/System.err(20144): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /temp.PDF
06-25 09:47:18.283: W/System.err(20144):    at id.dutapulsa.bayartagihan.extension.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:327)
06-25 09:47:18.283: W/System.err(20144):    at id.dutapulsa.bayartagihan.extension.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:89)
06-25 09:47:18.283: W/System.err(20144):    at id.dutapulsa.bayartagihan.DownloadListPDF$1.onItemClick(DownloadListPDF.java:56)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1300)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3034)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3834)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
06-25 09:47:18.284: W/System.err(20144):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what value in your "requestFile"

Comment: File requestFile = new File(mPDFFilenames[position]);
and the mPDFFilenames get from item in listview

Comment: Kindly print this requestFile before use and show me please.